# Cursor Trigger em alocação de livro

Tags: postgresql, trigger, cursor, plpgsql

Bem, tenho uma tabela chamada LOCACAO_LIVRO nela tenho informações de LIVRO e CLIENTE quando ocorrer um insert ou update de alocação então será informado o id_cliente, id_livro, a data_de_saida e a partir desta data será gerada a data_de_previssao_entrega que somará 7 dias a data de saida, para isso criei uma tabela chamada alocacao_livro,uma trigger e um cursor seguem os códigos abaixo.Desde já mito grato!

```
-- TABELA LIVRO
CREATE TABLE LIVRO(
ID_LIVRO SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ISBN INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NOME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
AUTOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
EDITORA VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ANO_PUBLICACAO INTEGER NOT NULL);

-- TABELA CLIENTE
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
ID_CLIENTE SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MATRICULA INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NOME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
TELEFONE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);

-- TABELA ALOCAÇÃO_LIVRO
CREATE TABLE LOCACAO_LIVRO(
ID_LOCACAO SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID_CLIENTE INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES CLIENTE,
ID_LIVRO INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES LIVRO,
DT_SAIDA DATE,
DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA DATE,
DT_ENTREGA DATE);
```

MINHA TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AF_CONTROLA_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO_TB_LOCACAO_LIVRO
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON LOCACAO_LIVRO
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO();
```

MINHA FUNÇÃO(CURSOR)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    VAR_ID_LOCACAO INTEGER;
    VAR_ID_CLIENTE INTEGER;
    VAR_ID_LIVRO INTEGER;
    VAR_DT_SAIDA DATE;
    VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA DATE;
    CURSOR_INSERE_DT_PREVISTA_ENTREGA CURSOR FOR SELECT
    ID_LOCACAO, ID_CLIENTE, ID_LIVRO, DT_SAIDA, DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA
    FROM LOCACAO_LIVRO
    WHERE ID_LOCACAO IS NOT NULL;
BEGIN
    OPEN CURSOR_INSERE_DT_PREVISTA_ENTREGA;
    FETCH CURSOR_INSERE_DT_PREVISTA_ENTREGA INTO VAR_ID_LOCACAO, VAR_ID_CLIENTE, VAR_ID_LIVRO, VAR_DT_SAIDA, VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA;
    WHILE FOUND LOOP
        VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA = VAR_DT_SAIDA + 7;

        IF(VAR_ID_LOCACAO IS NOT NULL)THEN
            UPDATE LOCACAO_LIVRO
                SET DT_SAIDA = VAR_DT_SAIDA, DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA = VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA
                WHERE ID_LOCACAO = VAR_ID_LOCACAO
                AND ID_CLIENTE = VAR_ID_CLIENTE
                AND ID_LIVRO = VAR_ID_LIVRO;
        END IF;
        FETCH CURSOR_INSERE_DT_PREVISTA_ENTREGA INTO VAR_ID_LOCACAO, VAR_ID_CLIENTE, VAR_ID_LIVRO, VAR_DT_SAIDA, VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE CURSOR_INSERE_DT_PREVISTA_ENTREGA;
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Edite sua resposta coloque os códigos corretamente e explique o que está a acontecer, por que até ai você apresentou tabelas e a sua trigger, mas não explicou qual é o problema.

Comment: Boa noite Nelson, esse é o erro que ocorre todas as vezes que tento inserir uma alocação na tabela alocacao_livro

cursor "cursor_insere_dt_prevista_entrega" already in use
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_gerar_dt_previsao_entrega_livro() line 13 at OPEN
SQL statement "UPDATE LOCACAO_LIVRO
    SET DT_SAIDA = VAR_DT_SAIDA, DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA = VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA
    WHERE ID_LOCACAO = VAR_ID_LOCACAO
    AND ID_CLIENTE = VAR_ID_CLIENTE
    AND ID_LIVRO = VAR_ID_LIVRO"
PL/pgSQL function fn_gerar_dt_previsao_entrega_livro() line 19 at SQL statement

********** Error **********

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se seu objetivo é somente adicionar a data de previsão de devolução, não tem por que utilizar um cursor, é só fazer sua trigger ser acionada antes do insert, pois na atualização você não fará isso pois a data já foi adicionada no insert e  na procedure adicionar a data segue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AF_CONTROLA_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO_TB_LOCACAO_LIVRO
BEFORE INSERT ON LOCACAO_LIVRO
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA DATE;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')  THEN //não precisa desse if, mas se for depois do update isso é necessário
        VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA := new.DT_SAIDA + 7;      
        new.DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA := VAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Dá ainda para fazer sem o uso daquela variável, ficaria assim:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO()
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS
 $$
 BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')  THEN
        new.DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA := new.DT_SAIDA + 7;   
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Mas isso pode ser feito mais facilmente direto na aplicação, porém não conheço os motivos pelo qual optou por esse tipo de implementação, mas se for fazer dessa forma daria ainda para validar se a data de empréstimo é diferente da atual e disparar a exceção do banco, visto que o empréstimo, presumo eu, deve ser cadastrado no dia da locação, segue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GERAR_DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA_LIVRO()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.DT_SAIDA <> CURRENT_DATE) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data de saída --> % é diferente da data atual',NEW.DT_SAIDA
        USING HINT = 'Data de saida deve ser igual a data atual';
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')  THEN
        new.DT_PREVISAO_ENTREGA := new.DT_SAIDA + 7;   
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Nelson sem palavras, vc é o cara, muito obrigado amigo!
Abraço!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu seu problema!